# how to use BCryptPasswordEncoder(int strength, SecureRandom random) func?

Tags: random, spring-security, bcrypt

I have spring security 3.2.0 in the project
here is the link
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html

somehow eclipse says this function is not in the package.I created securerandom for this

BCryptPasswordEncoder(int strength, SecureRandom random)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is my mistake as I use securandom improperly.